# Cloudfoundry application with Jboss buildpack fails to deploy

Tags: spring, jboss, cloud-foundry

I'm investigating features of Pivotal Cloudfoundry (http://run.pivotal.io) and now I'm trying to deploy simple Spring-powered application (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/) on Cloudfoundry using Jboss buildpack (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/jboss-buildpack).

After executing

```
cf push -p target/petclinic.war -b https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/jboss-buildpack.git
```

deployment starts, and CLI indicates that deployment process finishes successfully. However logs in CF web interface show

```
ERR: Error cloning to /tmp/buildpack/jboss
```

and it seems that CF tries to reclone buildpack again and again and is unable to start the application. Application is actually not started.

So the question is: what's wrong with CF and Jboss buildpack or is it something with the deployment process?